# Trying to access JSON endpoint using Javascript with X-Auth-Token leads to error

Tags: javascript, json, api, authentication, endpoint

I am trying to access a JSON endpoint using Javascript with X-Auth-Token but I’m keeping getting error. It’s JSON for a sports API and I’ve followed every instruction in the documentation and code seems to correct to my knowledge however, I can’t spot the problem.

```
var main = function() {
var url = "https://api.football-data.org/v4/teams/86/matches?status=SCHEDULED";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "601a163917fe417da759316ced98462d");
xhr.send(null);
var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
return data;};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ‘A JavaScript exception occurred’

Comment: For sure it will be a javascript exception, what is the context of the error?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the [request mode to no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) for it to allow cross-origin resource sharing.

Try doing this.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("X-Auth-Token", "your token");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow',
  mode: 'no-cors'
};

fetch("https://api.football-data.org/v4/matches?status=FINISHED", requestOptions)
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Hope it helps.